# Ghostscript with LaTeX and rotate page

Tags: latex, ghostscript

I am using this command with gs 9.5 for LaTeX pdfs

```
gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -sOutputFile=foo-compressed.pdf foo.pdf
```

All works well, except that single pages I rotated in LaTeX from Landscape to Portrait (e.g. wide Tables) appear in the GS output again in Landscape format. The original LaTeX PDF looks fine, the PDF file output of LaTeX is simply too large (over 100MB)

Is there a way to stop gs rotating single pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation on AutoRotatePages.

Comment: Thanks, documentation: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/Use.htm, I tried -dORIENT1=true, and -dORIENT1=false; it does not work :-|

Comment: AutoRotatePages I said. https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/VectorDevices.htm

Comment: Found it, fantastic, just adding -dAutoRotatePages=/None does this trick. Thank you KenS